# how to eliminate points intersection between two spheres

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Please Sir, can you tell me how can I correct this code
the idea is to eliminate intersection points in my spheres because it make my figure not clear
Here is a party of my code
this is how I saved coordinates

```
int nombre=0;

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    Sphere *s = &sphereTree.nodes.index(sphNum);//this is a sphere

    Point rt(s->c.x, s->c.y, s->c.z);//this is the center
    Vpoint.push_back(rt);//I saved centers here
    Vrayon.push_back(s->r);//I saved  radiu of spheres
    std::vector<Point> pp;
    pp=triangulateSphere(rt, s->r);//the points of sphere (rt,s->r)

    for (int indice=0;indice<pp.size();indice++)
    { 
        Point p1=pp[indice];
        tableau2[i].push_back(p1);//I saved points of sphere i in //tableau2[i];
    }

    nombre++;
}
```

Then to get only points that is not included in other spheres I did like this

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
for(int indsphere=0; indsphere<=nombre;indsphere++)// the spheres indexes
{
    for (int indautresphere = 0;indautresphere<=nombre;indautresphere++)//other spheres created
    {
        if(indsphere!=indautresphere)
        {
            for (int nbrpointsi=0;nbrpointsi<tableau2[indsphere].size();nbrpointsi++)
            {
                float v1=(tableau2[indsphere][nbrpointsi].x)-(Vpoint[indautresphere].x);
                float v2=(tableau2[indsphere][nbrpointsi].y)-(Vpoint[indautresphere].y);
                float v3=(tableau2[indsphere][nbrpointsi].z)-(Vpoint[indautresphere].z);
                float val=sqrt(v1*v1+v2*v2+v3*v3);//calculate distance between points

                if(val >= (Vrayon[indautresphere]))
                    glVertex3fv(&((tableau2[indsphere][nbrpointsi]).x));
            }
        }
    }
}

glEnd();
```

this has not compilation errors but it shows all points even those having intersection whith other spheres. It doesn't eliminate any point

Answer (score 0):

You currently add the vertex if the point is outside any other Sphere...

Following may help:

```
// You should already have a function
// to compute (Square-)distance between 2 Points
const float square_distance(const Point& p, const Point& p2)
{
    const float diffx = p.x - p2.x;
    const float diffy = p.y - p2.y;
    const float diffz = p.z - p2.z;
    return diffx * diffx + diffy * diffy + diffz * diffz;
}

bool isInsideSphere(const Point& p, const Point& center, float radius)
{
    // we compare square instead of squareRoot for efficiency.
    return square_distance(p, center) <= radius * radius;
}
```

And then:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= nombre; ++i) {                // the spheres indexes
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
    for (int j = 0; j < tableau2[i].size(); ++j) { // each point
        bool is_present_in_other_sphere = false;
        for (int k = 0; k <= nombre; ++k) {        //other spheres created
            if (i != k) { continue; }

            if (isInsideSphere(tableau2[i][j], Vpoint[k], Vrayon[k])) {
                is_present_in_other_sphere = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (is_present_in_other_sphere == false) {
            glVertex3fv(&tableau2[i][j].x);
        }
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

Comment: thank you very much Sir for help but it gives exactly the same results and it keeps points of sphere s1 which exist inside other spheres.

Comment: @user3320319: Ok, just saw an other error you did: You don't draw sphere by sphere but as a whole, so there is a triangle between each sphere... Try the edited answer (`glBegin` and `glEnd` are in the loop).

Comment: Excuse me so much, I really did'nt find solution yet. It's the same thing

Comment: Can you show a problematic image ? BTW the different code should not display the same thing... (but may display something you don't want...)

Comment: this is the picture I obtained. As you see it keeps intersetions between spheres

Comment: @user3320319: Debug with 2 spheres. What are the red lines ? Are you sure sphere intersects and are not just behind each other (with wire frame we see throw the sphere) ?

Comment: I tried to verify and they really intersect and I also modified this instruction if (is_present_in_other_sphere == false) to true and I have no point shown so I think there is a problem in this code and it really keeps all points. The red line are from an other object

Comment: Try simple cases: `Sphere(Point(0, 0, 0), 2)` vs `Sphere(Point(0, 0, 0), 3)` (globally inside, S1 should not be displayed). `Sphere(Point(0, 0, 0), 2)` vs `Sphere(Point(4, 0, 0), 3)` (small intersection, you may try it with different direction (x, then y, then z))... I am really confident of intersection code (less in drawing code)...

Comment: I tried it and I evec counted the number of points shown. I used 1296 for s1 and 1296 and it drew 2592 points in two cases.

Comment: In the case with sphere inside the other, you should always step into `isInsideSphere(tableau2[i][j], Vpoint[k], Vrayon[k])` for one sphere and never for the other. Add a breakpoint why it is not the case (are all args correct ?).

Comment: I think I found the problem, I tried t minimize the number of points and to work with just a part of sphere it seems that it shows only points who don'i intersect but when I turn to see in other position they intersect. what should I do know?

Comment: You mean the projections on screen intersect (the spheres themselves don't)? I mean one sphere is "behind" the other sphere, and you still see it (which is normal) ?

Comment: I mean that I think points which intersect diseappear whith this code but I still seeing them. I think that and you can see if I'm right with this picture

Comment: Excuse me this is the picture http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/501404/res-bmp.html

Comment: Left image seems strange, only both top sphere are skipped... right image doesn't seems to be the same coord than the left image...